# How to change the name of Windows phone application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 project under VS 2013.

I go to PivotPange.xaml, and ItemPage.xaml and change from:

```
<Pivot x:Uid="Pivot" Title="My Application" x:Name="pivot" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
```

to

```
<Pivot x:Uid="Pivot" Title="New Title" x:Name="pivot" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
```

But after I rebuild and re-run it under emulator, the title does not change. Can you please tell how can I change the title of the Windows app?

Comment: did you try the `clean solution` when you right click the solution? also try deleting anywhere there are files generated by the build process. usually the bin and obj folders for the project

Comment: Yes. I did. It did not solve my problem. In the UI designer panel (left to my PivotPage.xaml), it does update with my new title. But when I run the app on emulator , it still shows the old title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you did was change the pivot text, not the application name. If you want to change the name of the application you have to edit the project's manifest.

To edit the manifest, go into the project properties (right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and select Properties).  In the project properties, click the **Application** tab.  Then click the **Package Manifest..** button.  In the Manifest Editor, change the **Display Name** of your application in the **Application** tab.

Comment: I tried your solution. But that still does not change the title in my application. On a related problem, when I change the "Header" in my PivotItem, that does not get updated when I run my application on emulator. I am sure I am compiling my project, as I insert a random character '8' in a random line, my project fails to compile.

Comment: I resolve my problem. I need to change it in Resources.resw file

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean up your project (Solution Explorer | right click project |
   Clean)
2. Solution Explorer | [project] | Properties | open
   WMAppManisfest.xml
3. On tab "Application UI" change "Display Name"
   field.